# Catching redirection (301) headers in angular app

Tags: angularjs, redirect

I have a scenario where I am getting headers from redirection happening on one URL, let's assume `www.xyz.com` to `www.abc.com`. Redirection contains response headers which are required for all further API calls.

`www.abc.com` is an Angular app. Is there any way where I can catch one response header in 301 redirections happening?